# Obtaining number of processed messages in RabbitMQ queue

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq, race-condition

I would like to obtain a number of acknowledged and unacknowledged messages in a RabbitMQ queue, programmatically. I'm using the Typescript SDK. I've searched around but people typically propose using the HTTP API, which is no use for me.

I'm using a test scenario where I emit X messages and then perform some computation based on those messages. However, as soon as I send the messages, "  queue.send(testMessage);", the consumer have not received the message yet.

I've put a timeout between sending a message and performing computation based on those messages, but it's time wasted:

```
  import * as amqp from "amqp-ts";
  const connection = new amqp.Connection();
  const queue = connection.declareQueue(queueName, { durable: false });


  let testMessage = new amqp.Message({
    "hello"
  });
  queue.send(testMessage);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

  // perform computation
```

Is it possible to only perform computation when the queue has processed X messages (known in advance)?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use two queues? One for messages to be processed and another one for the processed messages. Or is this out of your control?

Comment: That could be done, but how do I know the amount of messages in each queue at each moment?

Comment: AmqpLib, a dependancy of amqp-ts, has checkQueue method which does return the messageCount. amqp-ts does not expose it, but you could fork it and add a method.

- The problem is I don't see why you need it. You can prefetch multiple messages from the processed queue, store them in an array, and when your array reaches X size do the computation and acknowledge them.

Comment: That looks like a better approach. Can you post an answer so I can give you the points? Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have control over the first processing step, you can split the messages into two queues. QueueA that contains the messages that have not been processed yet, and QueueB where the message is published after processing.

As for processing in batches, you can store un-acknowledged messages from QueueA in memory, trigger the processing in some other way (when X messages are in memory, every X minutes, etc.), and acknowledge them and publish into QueueB.

Do note [automatic requeueing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#automatic-requeueing) occurs if the processing service is killed with unacknowledged messages held. I think there was a 24h timeout for requeueing even if the connection is still up, but I can't find it in the docs.